# How to update one columns data using another tables data TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-update

I have just realised I have been capturing the wrong data for one column in my table. I have fixed the problem, however, the data I have captured thus far remains incorrect.

Let's name my tables `TableIWantToCorrect` and `TableWithIDs`

In `TableIWantToCorrect`, I have a foreign key to `TableWithIDs`. This is what is incorrect.

I am able to correct the data by comparing substring of a column in `TableIWantToCorrect` with a column in `TableWithIDs`.

So currently, I have

**TableIWantToCorrect**

```
Name            ForeignKey
123-abc-123        15
456-def-456        15
789-ghi-789        15
```

**TableWithIDs**

```
CompareName    id
abc            1
def            2
ghi            3
```

So I want to update `TableIWantToCorrect` to have the correct ForeignKey value when the substring in the Name equals the substring in Compare name. The position of the substring is always the same so I can use the `Substring` method.

My attempt :

```
Update TableIWantToCorrect
SET ForeignKey =
       (SELECT id 
        FROM TableWithIDs 
        WHERE UPPER(CompareName) = UPPER((SUBSTRING(TableIWantToCorrect.Name, 4, 3)))
```

The result :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

I know I have done something silly. What have I done incorrectly here ?

Comment: Your inline-query is returning more that one row hence the issue. Run this query to figure out which ones are repeating `SELECT CompareName , COUNT(1)
 FROM TableWithIDs 
GROUP BY CompareName 
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 
`

Comment: Do you still get the error if you change the subquery to use `SELECT DISTINCT id`? If so there are multiple possible matches and it is ambiguous which one to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPDATE from SELECT using SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is because your subquery is returning more than one record for the `UPDATE`.  To fix this, you can do this using a `JOIN` with your `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE t1
SET ForeignKey = t2.id
FROM TableIWantToCorrect t1
INNER JOIN TableWithIDs t2
    ON UPPER(t2.CompareName) = UPPER(SUBSTRING(t1.Name, 4, 3))
```

Comment: I know this is specifically a SQL Server question, but if you want MySQL equivalents for doing this, try here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11709090/403264

Answer (score 2):

```
 Update TableIWantToCorrect
 SET ForeignKey =  s.id
 FROM TableIWantToCorrect , TableWithIDs as s
 WHERE UPPER(s.CompareName) = UPPER( (SUBSTRING(TableIWantToCorrect.Name, 4, 3))
```

Comment: You can always tell who works in Oracle, they never use the join command.  ;)

Comment: Unfortunately i swing in between Oracle and Sql server so some time i do get confused ..! nevertheless they yield the same result but still join should be preferred .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause

Comment: I was 10 years in Oracle, and I used to hate the join statement! For some reason, I always found it harded to read, but after years in SQL server, I have seen the errors of my ways and always use joins.

Answer (score -1):

```
--CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_FindReports 
--(@InEmpID INTEGER)
--RETURNS @retFindReports TABLE 
--(
--    EmployeeID int primary key NOT NULL,
--    FirstName nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
--    LastName nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
--    JobTitle nvarchar(50) NOT NULL

--)
----Returns a result set that lists all the employees who report to the 
----specific employee directly or indirectly.*/
--AS
--BEGIN
--WITH EMP_cte(EmployeeID, OrganizationNode, FirstName, LastName, JobTitle, RecursionLevel) -- CTE name and columns
--    AS (
--        SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.ManagerID, p.FirstName, p.LastName, P.JobTitle, 0 -- Get the initial list of Employees for Manager n
--        FROM HumanResources.Employee e 
--INNER JOIN Person.Person p 
--ON p.Employeeid = e.EmployeeID
--        WHERE e.EmployeeID = @InEmpID
--        UNION ALL
--        SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.ManagerID, p.FirstName, p.LastName, P.JobTitle, RecursionLevel + 1 -- Join recursive member to anchor
--        FROM HumanResources.Employee e 
--            INNER JOIN EMP_cte
--            ON e.ORGANIZATIONNODE.GetAncestor(1) = EMP_cte.OrganizationNode
--INNER JOIN Person.Person p 
--ON p.Employeeid= e.EmployeeID
--        )
---- copy the required columns to the result of the function 
--   INSERT @retFindReports
--   SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, JobTitle, RecursionLevel
--   FROM EMP_cte 
--   RETURN
--END;
--GO

>
```