# mysql update column with value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables, both looking like

```
id  name  value
===================
1   Joe     22
2   Derk    30
```

I need to copy the value of `value` from `tableA` to `tableB` based on check name in each table.

Any tips for this `UPDATE` statement?

Answer (score 600, accepted):

In addition to this answer if you need to change tableB.value according to tableA.value dynamically you can do for example:

```
UPDATE tableB
INNER JOIN tableA ON tableB.name = tableA.name
SET tableB.value = IF(tableA.value > 0, tableA.value, tableB.value)
WHERE tableA.name = 'Joe'
```

Comment: yep, `INNER JOIN` is perfect in this situation. I also used `CONCAT_WS` to merge pruduct name and SKU from another table

Comment: Is there a way to do this using aliases?

Comment: I tryed this but no success, because the "affected rows" count gives me 5690, but the total rows are 59643, why? this is the query: `UPDATE participants_registrations
INNER JOIN participants ON participants.id = participants_registrations.participantId
INNER JOIN registrations ON registrations.id = participants_registrations.registrationId
LEFT JOIN groups ON (groups.id = registrations.groupId)
SET 
    registrations.groupId = groups.id,
    registrations.groupName = groups.name,
    participants.memberOfGroupName = groups.name`

Comment: This doesn't work. tableB still has its own data w/o changing. https://wtools.io/paste-code/bzWA A sample based on OP and this answer.

Comment: @sniffingdoggo That's because your datasets in Table A and B don't match at all. Your `INNER JOIN` is joining on `name` and your WHERE is looking for TableA.name.
The JOIN won't happen, since there's no records to join on, and therefore you can't update TableB where the name is Joe, because there aren't any records matching that criteria.

Answer (score 213):

you need to join the two tables:

for instance you want to copy the value of `name` from tableA into `tableB` where they have the same `ID`

```
UPDATE tableB t1 
        INNER JOIN tableA t2 
             ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.name = t2.name 
WHERE t2.name = 'Joe'
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
UPDATE tableB t1 
        INNER JOIN tableA t2 
             ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.name = t2.name
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
UPDATE tableB t1 
        INNER JOIN tableA t2 
             ON t1.name = t2.name
SET t1.value = t2.value
```

Comment: ive over 1k record with different names and value , here your saying just for 1st record

Comment: you can just remove the `where` clause or modify the `where` clause depending on your needs..

Comment: also table B  got more records than table A , my idea  is  check from table B to a if the name exist copy the value of " value" to table B ,!

Comment: i don't know if i understood your question clearly, can you check my updated answer?

Comment: i did try both update,  the 2nd one says effeced on 734 rows  , i checked values still all 0 not changed

Comment: can you give atleast records from tableA and tableB and with the new values of tableB? willing to help here :)

Comment: I got it error was here SET t1.value = t2.value  , its should beSET t2.value = t1.value  other wise will update the main table which happen to me :)  glad ive backup thanks for the tips works like sharp

Comment: thanks for this @JW웃 I have been searching around for this functionality for a while, just wondering, what would a select statement using the inner join look like (i'm curious to see what is happening here) Tnx.

Comment: @shnozolla something like this, `SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM tableB t1 
        INNER JOIN tableA t2 
             ON t1.name = t2.name`

Comment: Does it have to be an inner join?

Answer (score 121):

Second possibility is,

```
UPDATE TableB 
SET TableB.value = (
    SELECT TableA.value 
    FROM TableA
    WHERE TableA.name = TableB.name
);
```

Comment: Yes, no need for complicated joins, when all we need is to update a field with a value from another table.

Comment: Yes this works fine but is very, very slow on large datasets. If you're working with small tables this method is fine but I recommend the JOIN as shown above for anything else.

Comment: Also, in this scenario, table A and B can't be the same table due to SQL constraints.

Comment: @frijj2k would this still be slow if `.name` is indexed on both tables?

Comment: @frijj2k - When I did this using the JOIN method, then reset the tables and repeated with the above method, the JOIN method was slower.

Comment: This answer is wrong. 2 issues: 1) This sql will update all rows in TableB. 2) If didn't find matched name in TableA, the subquery will return NULL thus TableB.value will be set to NULL.

Answer (score 31):

```
    UPDATE    cities c,
          city_langs cl
    SET       c.fakename = cl.name
   WHERE     c.id = cl.city_id
```

Comment: This is simplest.

Comment: Love this, very versatile

Answer (score 4):

The second option is feasible also if you're using safe updates mode (and you're getting an error indicating that you've tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column), by adding:

```
UPDATE TableB  
SET TableB.value = (  
SELECT TableA.value  
    FROM TableA  
    WHERE TableA.name = TableB.name  
)  
**where TableB.id < X**  
;
```

Answer (score 3):

Store your data in temp table

```
Select * into tempTable from table1
```

Now update the column

```
 UPDATE table1
    SET table1.FileName = (select FileName from tempTable where tempTable.id = table1.ID);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the accepted solution was just too slow. For a table with 180K rows the rate of updates was about 10 rows per second. This is with the indexes on the join elements.

I finally resolved my issue using a procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`my_procedure`@`%` PROCEDURE `rescue`()
BEGIN
    declare str VARCHAR(255) default '';
    DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur_name VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE cur_value VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '';
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA INTO n;
    SET i=0;
    WHILE i<n DO 
      SELECT namea,valuea FROM tableA limit i,1 INTO cur_name,cur_value;
      UPDATE tableB SET nameb=cur_name where valueb=cur_value;
      SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

END
```

I hope it will help someone in the future like it helped me