# MySQL Update Column from another column in same table

Tags: mysql

I got a problem on updating column from another column in same table. I know this question is duplicate. But here is the situation. I have this table structure:

```
  login   |   card_id   | card_serial
--------------------------------------
  A1149     1446700898    NULL
  A672      1446845746    NULL
  A626      1446581746    NULL
```

Now, I want to update card_serial column with hex value using hex function. The data supposed to be like this:

```
  login   |   card_id   | card_serial
--------------------------------------
  A1149     1446700898    62E73A56
  A672      1446845746    321D3D56
  A626      1446581746    F2153956
```

But when I try to update card_serial column with my SQL statement, it always return value **36343431**.

This is my statement:

```
UPDATE card_id_without_serial a 
JOIN card_id_without_serial b ON b.login = a.login
SET a.card_serial = concat(substring(hex(b.card_id), 7,2), substring(hex(b.card_id), 5,2), substring(hex(b.card_id), 3,2), substring(hex(b.card_id), 1,2));
```

Please help me and thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql update column with value from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709043/mysql-update-column-with-value-from-another-table)

Comment: Why are you using a join? You can just update your column with a regular update. `UPDATE table_name SET col3 = HEX(col2)`;

Comment: Hi chrisShick, I already try your suggestion, but it still return value 36343431. That's y i try to join the table. But the problem still not solve

Comment: No, chrisShick's answer is correct. You must have done the update incorrectly.