# how to create column with same values and structure from another one in sql database

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I create a column and copy the values and structure from an existing column from another table?

My try:

```
CREATE COLUMN database.table.column SELECT * FROM database.table2.column
```

Comment: Please tell are you using MySQL server or SQL server?

Answer (score 2):

If you are copy to a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable 
SELECT columnname
FROM table2
```

If you want to add a new column to an existing table, you need

```
ALTER TABLE existing_table ADD column new_col . . .
```

And you need to update existing_table based on keys

```
UPDATE existing_table
SET new_col = (
    SELECT columnname
    FROM table1
    WHERE . . .
)
```

Depends on how your situation, there is also a lazy way:

```
SELECT existing_table.*, table1.columnname
FROM existing_table, table1
WHERE . . .
```

Comment: @DavidM:  The challenge is to add the right row value for each row in the existing table.

Comment: @wallyk Here's an example of how to update a column in a table based on the values of another table. [mysql update column with value from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19346375/21353). So add the new column with the `Alter Table` statement and then create an update query to set the values of the new column.

Answer (score 1):

To copy full table structure and values

```
SELECT * INTO NewTableName FROM ExistingTableName
```

To copy specific structure and value

```
SELECT ExistingTableName.Column1,ExistingTableName.Column2 INTO NewTableName FROM ExistingTableName
```

[SAMPLE QUERY](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/429465)