# update tables value from another table in mysql where updated field is foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to table like this. Now `tbl2.transaction_id` is from `tbl1.id`. I wanna to update `tbl2.transaction_id` with `tbl1.id_trans` values that `transaction_id` now pointed to them. Can I do this with just one query? Thanks.

```
tbl1
+------+----------------+
| id   | id_trans       |
+------+----------------+
|   53 | 531            |
|   54 | 532            |
|   55 | 533            |
|   56 | 554            |
|   57 | 555            |
+------+----------------+


tbl2
+------+----------------+
| id   | transaction_id |
+------+----------------+
|   10 | 53             |
|   11 | 55             |
|   12 | 56             |
+------+----------------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql update column with value from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709043/mysql-update-column-with-value-from-another-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Update with join:

```
UPDATE tbl2 t
INNER JOIN tbl1 s
 ON(t.transaction_id = s.id)
set t.transaction_id = s.id_trans
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
update tbl2
set tbl2.transaction_id = tbl1.id_trans 
from tbl1 inner join tbl2
on tbl1.id = tbl2.transaction_id
where tbl2.transaction_id = 53;
```

Comment: Tnx. But I don't want just tbl1.id = 53! My tables have much data

Comment: @pk19000 it's up to you whether you need to use where clause or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
    UPDATE tbl2
INNER JOIN tbl1 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.transaction_id
SET
    tbl2.transaction_id = tbl1.id_trans
```

Comment: Tnx. But I don't want just `tbl1.id = 53`! My tables have much data.

Comment: You want the transaction_id of tbl2 to be replaced with the id_trans of tbl1 or replaced with the id of tbl1?In this case it is replaced with the id_trans

Comment: Tnx for yuor answer.