# php mysql update and redistribute all rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I wanted to update MySQL table with certain rules. I have let's say 3 column: `ID, Name, Checked` and I want to update `Name` to all rows equally where `Checked = 0`. In another table I have list 'Names` from where I pull my names.

Is this possible to do with one `UPDATE` query, or do i need to use some loop? Will there be a problem if let's say I have 11 rows to update but i have 10 names, how the query update those fields.

Comment: yes that could happen, update table based on condition with using set on another table. you could search here on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709043/mysql-update-column-with-value-from-another-table

Comment: The Name field consists of single value or multiple values ? It'll be better if you could post the Db table structures to gain better clarity.

Comment: The `Name` field is names of employees. List of active employees is listed in another table. So every once in a month I want to update the remaining unchecked row with new employees and redistribute equally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `ID` = (select `ID` from `name` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) WHERE `Lock_ID` = 0
```

This query will randomly use name from other table and update it (it is 99% correct solution) it will redistribute name's almost the same for every row.