# mysql copy data from table to another with the same value?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to update my table from another table

I need to update the IP in table1 from the new_IP in table changeip according to the SIM number (whcih is the same on both tables)

I have try to do it from what it say here : 
[mysql update column with value from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709043/mysql-update-column-with-value-from-another-table)

```
I get error "IP can't be null"
```

this is what I wrote in the command line

```
    UPDATE table1 
SET table1.IP = (
    SELECT changeip.New_IP 
    FROM changeip
    WHERE table1.SIM_NEW = changeip.SIM_Number 
);
```

what am I doing wrong ?

****************update

this is table1

'10.226.202.169', '8997250000031944123'

'10.226.202.170', '8997250000031944131'

'10.226.202.173', '8997250000031944164'

'10.136.136.101', '8997250400019201597'

'10.136.136.102', '8997250400019201589'

'10.136.136.103', '8997250400019201571'

'10.136.136.104', '8997250400019201563'

and so on........

this is changeip table

'10.226.202.169', '8997250000031944123', '10.136.137.221'

'10.226.202.170', '8997250000031944131', '10.136.137.222'

'10.226.202.173', '8997250000031944164', '10.136.137.223'

'10.226.202.174', '8997250000031944172', '10.136.137.224'

'10.226.202.175', '8997250000031944180', '10.136.137.225'

'10.226.202.177', '8997250000031944206', '10.136.137.226'

Thanks ,

Comment: table1.IP must be null, alter the column from not null to null. As changeip.New_IP contains null values

Comment: Seems to be a typo aswell, " WHERE table1.SIM_NEW = hangeip.SIM_Number "

Comment: what should happen if an IP is null in the changeip table? Should it get updated to null or stay with the old IP?

Comment: @Kool-Mind, but table1.IP has a value inside ... I want to overwrite it - all this colom is fill with data . there is no empty cell there.        and about what isaace say  - can't be null - this is a 100% table with data , no empty\null in the changeip.IP table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `join` and `update`

```
 UPDATE table1 t
    inner join changeip p
    on t.SIM_NEW= p.SIM_Number
   and t.IP=p.old_ip
    SET t.IP =p.New_IP
```

Comment: when I run this - I don't get any error, but it doesn't update nothing ....

Comment: @David12123 can.you please share both tables data ,because it supposed to be worked

Comment: tell me how to do it and I will

Comment: @David12123 if you have both tables SIM_Number number it will join and update  your table1

Comment: do you have multiple New_IP  against table1 sim_number?

Comment: I have update the question with some information and example of my DB - maybe it will help you help me:-)

Comment: @David12123 can you just share with me table1 sample data and changeip tables data

Comment: @David12123 it will be easy for me to do it if could give those things

Comment: @David12123 10.226.202.169 this old ip of changeip table right?

Comment: say that Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't.SIM_Number' in 'on clause'

Comment: @David12123  does SIM_Number column in your table?

Comment: @David12123 i missed column name of tabe1 could check plz

Comment: @David12123 table1 columns name IP,SIM_NEW and  changeip columns name old_ip,SIM_Number,New_IP am i right?

Comment: now it's working ! , Thanks - can you explain to me what was the problem so I will learn for next time ?

Comment: @David12123 actually column name was mistake and for updating two tables you need join two table by using their join keys

Comment: just to understand - from what I see you make a "rule" to update new IP according to where SIM number is the same (t.SIM_NEW= p.SIM_Number) and also where the old IP is the same (and t.IP=p.old_ip) .    whouldn't 1 condition (sim number is the same) would be enough?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER table1 MODIFY IP varchar(20) null;
```

alter the column from not null to null if the other table consist null values

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you want to update those that have an IP on the `changeip` table and leaves those that don't have a new IP with the old IP:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET table1.IP = (
    SELECT changeip.New_IP 
    FROM changeip
    WHERE table1.SIM_NEW = hangeip.SIM_Number 
    AND hangeip.New_IP IS NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I get this error : Error Code: 1048. Column 'IP' cannot be null.                            , which can't be becasue all of table1.IP have data inside - I'm replacing old IP with new IP.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve the required result is as follows:

Based on your data the start tables are

[image]

and

[image]

If you run the query

```
UPDATE table1, changeip 
  SET table1.IP = changeIP.old_IP 
  WHERE table1.SIM = changeip.SIM_Number
```

The outcome is as follows:

[image]

Which I believe is the desired result. Most of the suggestions above are missing the WHERE clause in the UPDATE statement and that is why they fail.