# Why does my UPDATE query take so long when my SELECT query doesn't?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am trying to do the following: let's say I have the following SELECT query (please excuse the german column names):

```
    SELECT  a1.aktivitäts_id, a1.herkunft_kontakt, a1.aktionsart,
            a1.aktionstyp, a2.aktivitäts_id, a2.herkunft_kontakt,
            a2.aktionsart, a2.aktionstyp, a2.datum
        FROM  Aktivitäten a1, Aktivitäten a2
        WHERE  a1.kunden_nr_aktivität = a2.kunden_nr_aktivität
          AND  a1.aktionsart = 'foo'
          AND  a2.herkunft_kontakt <> ''
```

This query takes about 4 seconds (the database has about 1 million records total) and returns about 400 records. However, when I want to UPDATE these same records with the following statement

```
    UPDATE  Aktivitäten a1, Aktivitäten a2
       SET a1.herkunft_kontakt = a2.herkunft_kontakt
        WHERE  a1.kunden_nr_aktivität = a2.kunden_nr_aktivität
          AND  a1.aktionsart = 'foo'
          AND  a2.herkunft_kontakt <> ''
```

The query always times out after taking forever. Am I doing something wrong or is this behaviour to be expected?

Comment: Could you please explain what you try to achieve with this update? Now it looks like CROSS JOIN

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql update column with value from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709043/mysql-update-column-with-value-from-another-table)

Comment: Where and when did you learn comma-separated joins? The have been obsolete for almost three decades now. Use explicit joins (e.g. `INNER JOIN`), which have been introduced in the SQL standard in 1992.

Comment: From your update statement I conclude that there is sometimes one row per `kunden_nr_aktivität` with a `herkunft_kontakt`, sometimes no such row, and never more than one such row. You only want to update rows with `aktionsart = 'foo'` where exists such a row for the `kunden_nr_aktivität`. Is this correct? If not then your updates statement is inappropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, learn to `JOIN`!!!  Second, the difference is probably that you are updating too many rows -- and probably one row multiple times.  I might suggest trying to aggregate *before* joining:

```
UPDATE Aktivitäten a1 JOIN
       (SELECT kunden_nr_aktivität, MAX(herkunft_kontakt) as herkunft_kontakt
        FROM Aktivitäten a2
        WHERE a2.herkunft_kontakt <> ''
        GROUP BY kunden_nr_aktivität
       ) a2
       USING (kunden_nr_aktivität)
     SET a1.herkunft_kontakt = a2.herkunft_kontakt 
WHERE a1.aktionsart = 'foo' ;
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to achieve! Thank you very much and I will keep the thing about joining explicitly in mind :).

Answer (score 0):

Composite indexes that may help:

```
a1:  (aktionsart, kunden_nr_aktivit)   -- in this order
a2:  (kunden_nr_aktivit, herkunft_kontakt)
```